# Horizontal Scrolling With JQuery Sortable List

Tags: scroll, horizontal-scrolling, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi i am having some trouble getting my sortable lists to scroll horizontally. Here is a [link](http://www.css-lab.com/demos/image-display/side-scroll-gallery.html) to an example of how i want my list to function.

The example above uses a very large negative margin to the right like so...

```
margin-right:-30000px;
```

And here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nLMn5/) to the Js-Fiddle version of my sortable list.

i have tried everything i know! Overflow properties, margins, divs within divs but i have had no luck. Searched around on Google to but everything i found just told me what i already know.

Hopefully someone on here has done this before or knows how to and would like to share their secrets with me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to divert from horizontal side scrolling for now as it just doesn't seem to have enough support at the moment. For anyone looking for a solution i found this neat plugin that is highly customizable. http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/complete_examples.html